In cursor paging using id and timestamp, do we need both id and timestamp to get the next page?
I am following this answer to paginate a table. As the title says, is it necessary to give both id and timestamp to get the next page? I am thinking of something like this:
select * from my_table where 
(date_created, id) < 
((select date_created from my_table where id = 1234), 1234)
order by date_created, id desc limit 10


I think you need to be a bit more specific. Can you provide some sample data and expected result? I also see you already have page ids, what exactly is their meaning? Do you use any pattern or framework here? What is the exact data structure (table definition)?

Yes it is necessary, because this is what you order your results by. If you only compared the date, it wouldn't work, because there can be many rows with the same date. If you only compared the id, you'd get a wrong order.

@ThorstenKettner I didn't say that I need just one of them. I know I need both of them. I am saying with just an id I can get the timestamp too.

The subquery is weird. Normally in pagination the client applicaation would hold on to the most recent values and pass them back as parameters.

If id is the primary key, then remembering the timestamp is not necessary, logically. (The second column is functionally dependent on id - corner cases with concurrent writes aside.) But besides being correct, pagination also needs to be fast. Obviously, remembering the timestamp is a lot faster than looking it up again, which would almost double the cost.
Also, using a unique ID as tiebreaker is just a special case. The general case of keyset pagination works with composite keys, where only the combination of two or more columns is unique. Then, remembering all of them is a bare logical necessity. See:

Optimize query with OFFSET on large table

BTW, "cursor pagination" is probably not the best keyword here. No obvious involvement of any "cursors". The key feature of your query is the set of keys used to establish a deterministic sort order for paging. "Keyset pagination" or "row value comparison" will be more fitting terms / keywords.
